# Trying to determine the switch type I need to shop for

Tags: switches, relay

I am trying to find a double-illuminated 12v rocker or pushbutton switch (one light for off, 2 lights for on, or at least different colors for on/ off), single-throw, on-off, but...

The circuit I want to close with the switch is a 5v continuity line that should be electrically segregated from the power going to the switch light.

Is there a standard switch type that does this without employing a relay of some kind?  Trying to keep this (relatively) simple.

Scenario:  I'm installing an AIS transponder in my boat that will receive and transmit telemetry (course over ground, size, type, name, and speed of vessel) over VHF to other vessels with the same type of equipment, but it's generally bad "manners" to transmit when you are in a marina or at anchor... so the unit has two wires coming out of it that, when connected, you transmit, and when disconnected, just receives.  I want to install a switch I can easily see in the dark that lets me know if I am transmitting or not.

If someone could tell me what I should be looking for, I'd really be grateful.  That way I can look it up on common websites and (hopefully) get one with a custom face for it.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: one option is to put a small current through a single led when off (so that it is visible in the dark) but put a higher current (so that it is bright) when it is on.

Comment: probasbly you are looking for some sort of industrial control they typically have illumination separate from switching, and everything as stackable options on the back,  it may be possible to stack two illumination layers to get two different colours,

Comment: Do you have a fully enclosed bridge? or ar you lookign for something splashproof?

Comment: I intend for this to be installed belowdecks, so I have some options...

Answer (score 2):

Digikey has a good search engine with filters
electromechanical>switches>Rocker> illuminated > Ctrl+ select after sort by illumination colour, Choose in stock only

[Results](https://www.digikey.ca/products/en/switches/rocker-switches/195?k=&pkeyword=&sv=1&pv522=358364&pv522=364353&pv522=364362&pv522=364379&pv522=364407&pv522=379783&sf=0&FV=1989%7C0%2C-8%7C195&quantity=&ColumnSort=-522&page=1&stock=1&pageSize=250)
e.g. [image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: This really doesn't answer my question... what should I be looking for?  What would it be called?  You gave some examples, but I don't think any of these are actually matching my criteria.  The first three don't look like I could have a custom face made for them, and the last looks like a Carling switch which uses 12VDC from illumination circuit to close the switched circuit.  Please educate me if I'm wrong.